# Combine loop with Rbind

Tags: r, loops, rbind

I'm trying to do a loop that appends through dataframes. I don't know how to call the dataframes in the loop when I use rbind. I tried with paste0 but didn't work. Here is a reproducible example:

```
library(metRology)

x <- c(1,2,3)
y <- c(1,2,3)

df_a_1 <- data.frame(x,y)
df_a_2 <- data.frame(x,y)

df_b_1 <- data.frame(x,y)
df_b_2 <- data.frame(x,y)

df_c_1 <- data.frame(x,y)
df_c_2 <- data.frame(x,y)

letters <- c("a", "b", "c")

#Loop
for (i in letters) {
  df_i <- rbind(paste0("df_", i "_1"), paste0("df", i, "_2"))
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How did you create all those `df_a/b_1/2` variables in the first place? Creating a bunch ov variables with data/indexes in their names is usually a bad code smell. Often in R things are much easier when you are working with named lists. There may be better ways to create those data sets in the first place which would simplify the problem. But `paste()` returns a character value, not a variable name. You can get the values of a variables form it's character name with `get()` but I'd strongly suggest avoiding that function.

Comment: Thanks for the response. In my original code those dataframes were columns of dataframes stored in a list. I extracted those columns and made them dataframes and now I'm trying to append them.

Comment: Did you use assign() to create them? I really think the real problem is further up the pipeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get and assign variables by their names assuming your data frames are stored in the R global environment:

```r
library(tidyverse)

x <- c(1,2,3)
y <- c(1,2,3)

df_a_1 <- data.frame(x,y)
df_a_2 <- data.frame(x,y)

df_b_1 <- data.frame(x,y)
df_b_2 <- data.frame(x,y)

df_c_1 <- data.frame(x,y)
df_c_2 <- data.frame(x,y)

letters <- c("a", "b", "c")

for(l in letters) {
  prefix <- str_glue("df_{l}")
  res <- names(globalenv()) %>%
         keep(~ .x %>% str_detect(prefix)) %>%
         map(get) %>%
         reduce(rbind)
  assign(prefix, res)
}

df_a
#>   x y
#> 1 1 1
#> 2 2 2
#> 3 3 3
#> 4 1 1
#> 5 2 2
#> 6 3 3
df_b
#>   x y
#> 1 1 1
#> 2 2 2
#> 3 3 3
#> 4 1 1
#> 5 2 2
#> 6 3 3
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>